# CompletableFuture's sometimes use wrong response from downstream service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I have this method in my Java application:

```
public void addPrices(
      Response Response,
      String startDate,
      IContext context)
      throws ServiceException {

    CompletableFuture<PayInfoFull> futurePrimary =
        futurePrimary(response, startDate, context, new PartMapImpl());
    CompletableFuture<PayInfoFull> futureSecondary =
        futureSecondary(response, startDate, context, new PayMapImpl());
    CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futurePrimary, futureSecondary);

    try {
      combinedFuture.get();
      PayInfoFull primaryPrice = futurePrimary.get();
      PayInfoFull secondaryPrice = futureSecondary.get();
      if (validatePrices(primaryPrice, secondaryPrice)) {
        populateDefaultresponse(response, primaryPrice, secondaryPrice);
      } else {
        response.getPrimary().setPrimaryPrice(null);
        response.getSecondary().setSecndaryPrice(null);
      }

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      LOGGER.error(String.format("Exception: - Exception: %s", e), e);
      throw new ServiceException(STATUS_DOWN);
    }
}
```

`primaryPrice` and `secondaryPrice` make the same call to a downstream service which returns the prices. `primaryPrice` should always be higher. However sometimes both will have the same price. I can check the messages that the downstream service returns and see that they are always correct but it's as if the `CompletableFuture`'s in this method only see one response and use it for both. How can I investigate this further and hopefully fix the issue?

Comment: It doesn't look like the problem is in this function; it might be in your `futurePrimary` and `futureSecondary`.